# When can we guarantee the existence of an object satisfying a given universal property, in purely category-theoretic terms?

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

I'm only just beginning to learn category theory, so apologies if this question has an obvious answer.

If I understand correctly, one of the reasons we care about universal properties is that they provide "nice" characterizations of objects whose specific, concrete construction might be rather unwieldy (free objects, tensor products, etc). But, showing that an object satisfying a given universal property actually *exists* in the first place typically requires recourse to these same unwieldy constructions.

Of course, this isn't too surprising, since a category doesn't contain any "new information" that wasn't already present in the concrete objects under consideration. But I'm wondering if there are any theorems that guarantee the existence of an object satisfying a given universal property, based on "simpler" purely category-theoretic criteria alone. By "simpler," I mean properties of a given category that might be easier or more natural to verify concretely than the messy construction of an object with a given universal property. It seems like such a result would also be necessary for showing the existence of objects satisfying a universal property in categories which are themselves constructed in purely category-theoretic terms.

Comment: It somewhat depends on the universal property, but if you're interested in limits (and, dually, colimits), there's the [existence theorem for limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory)#Existence_of_limits) which says that if you have all products and equalizers, you have all limits - which is sometimes easier to check. (There's also some classes of categories, especially relating to algebra, where limits are known, but I'll leave it for someone more familiar with category theory to discuss)

Comment: If we have a monadic functor, then we can know a diagram in the domain category is a limit diagram simply by knowing that it maps to a limit in the codomain (where it may be much easier to check). Sometimes it's easier to show that a functor is monadic than it is to check some construction every time. I don't know if this is quite what you're thinking, though.